# What is the purpose of the GUID in a WP7 application?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, guid

What is the purpose of the GUID in a WP7 application and can they be changed with ease?

Comment: GUIDs can be used for many things. Are you referring to the app GUID?

Comment: yes an wp7 app guid :) I also see theres more than one GUID if you look deep into notepad files

Comment: Why do you want/need to change that GUID?  It uniquely identifies your application to the phone and (I believe) to the WP7 marketplace.

Comment: No I was just curious why it was editable in the 'Assembly Information' dialog box

Comment: Because it is part of the configuration and guess what - it can be changed. Same way you can blow up your house - it is also possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The GUID is used to identify the app on the phone and in the marketplace. After acceptance in the marketplace, a new GUID will be assigned to your app by Microsoft so you should always use that GUID from then on so that your upgrades etc will target the same app.